\input not loading tikzset definitions from standalone
I made the following tikz as a standalone .tex and wanted to \input the file into another. It compiles as a syandalone but it wont load the tikz boxes and arrows when imported.
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows, positioning}

\tikzset{
  startstop/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black},
  process/.style={rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black},
  decision/.style={diamond, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black},
  arrow/.style={thick,->,>=stealth}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]

% Nodes
\node (start) [startstop] {Inicio: Valor Inicial $n(\mathbf{r})$};
\node (potencial) [process, below of=start, align=center] { Calcular Potencial Efectivo\\
    $v_{eff}(\mathbf{r})=V_{en}(\mathbf{r}) + \int\frac{n(\mathbf{r'})}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'}|}d\mathbf{r'} + V_{xc}[n(\mathbf{r})]$ };
\node (solveKS) [process, below of=potencial, align=center] {Resolver Ecuaciones de Kohn-Sham\\
    $\left[-\frac{\hbar^{2}}{2m_{e}}\nabla_{i}^{2} + v_{eff}\right]\Psi_{i}=E_{i}\Psi_{i}$ };
\node (calcRho) [process, below of=solveKS, align=center] {Evaluar la Densidad de Electrones y la Energía Total\\ $n(\mathbf{r})=\sum_{i}|\Psi_{i}(\mathbf{r})|^{2} \rightarrow E_{tot}[n(\mathbf{r})]$ };
\node (decision) [decision, below of=calcRho, yshift=-1cm, align=center]
    {Convergencia\\de $n(\mathbf{r})$};
\node (updateRho) [process, left of=decision, xshift=-3cm, align=center] {Actualizar $n(\mathbf{r})$};
\node (end) [startstop, below of=decision, yshift=-1cm, align=center] { \text{Resultados}\\ $n_{0}(\mathbf{r})$, $E_{i}\[n_{0}(\mathbf{r})\]$ };
% Arrows
\draw [arrow] (start) -- (potencial);
\draw [arrow] (potencial) -- (solveKS);
\draw [arrow] (solveKS) -- (calcRho);
\draw [arrow] (calcRho) -- (decision);
\draw [arrow] (decision) -- node[anchor=east] {sí} (end);
\draw [arrow] (decision) -- node[anchor=south] {no} (updateRho);
\draw [arrow] (updateRho) |- (solveKS);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

Then import:
\documentclass[letter]{article}

\usepackage{tikz, pgf}
\usepackage{mathrsfs, amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{standalone}


\begin{document}
\title{Input Ti\textit{k}Z}
\date{}

\maketitle

\begin{figure}[htpb]
    \centering
    \input{khon-sham-scheme.tex}
    \caption{Kohn-Sham Ansatz}
    \label{fig:khon-sham}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

It compiles as a standalone file, but when importing it with \input, it wont load the \tikzset definitions
EDIT:
Part of the problem were some errors related to math environments.
There were portions of the tikz file that had errors in the math environments. for example:
$E_{i}\[n_{0}(\mathbf{r})\]$

should be
$E_{i}\left[n_{0}(\mathbf{r})\right]$

This prompted errors like:
error| LaTeX Error: Bad math environment delimiter.
LaTeX Error: \begin{tikzpicture} on input line 12 ended by \end    {equation*}.


@JohnKormylo: The standalone tikz option is not related to the problem.

Then agian, it serves no useful function in the given code either.

You can include the sub-preamble in your main document with subpreambles=true like this:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\title{Input Ti\textit{k}Z}
\maketitle
\begin{figure}
\centering
\input{khon-sham-scheme.tex}
\caption{Kohn-Sham Ansatz}
\label{fig:khon-sham}
\end{figure}
\end{document}

Or you could move the styles away from the preamble by giving them as options to the TikZ picture like this:
\begin{tikzpicture}[
startstop/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black},
process/.style={rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black},
decision/.style={diamond, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black},
arrow/.style={thick,->,>=stealth},
node distance=2cm,
]


Your second suggestion worked for me. I still don't know why this is needed as I have other figures with similar settings that did not provoke this behavior.
